# why a new Thread can touch view

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable, thread-exceptions, android-threading

as we know in Android applications we can touch views just from `Main/UI Thread` and otherwise an `CalledFromWrongThreadException` throws with below message:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

but when I touch just 1 time at `onCreate()`, this Exception does not throw and "Hello Again!" sets on `TextView`

```
 TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tv.setText("Hello Again!");
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Do you know why?

Comment: It looks like your runnable completes before onStart method, so may be view for that moment are not actually owned be Main/UI Thread.

Comment: @Raskilas It means  `onCreate()` does not run on MainThread? I copied this snipped code to `onStart()` too. and it ran correctly.

Comment: I suppose that your code just add Runnable to event queue, and it won't work if you will the same in AsyncTask in doInBackground().

Comment: Hmm... what is `tv's` original text, as specified in the layout file? It may be important.

Comment: the original text is default "Hello world!" and there is no problem in layout and inflating and etc. @greeble31

Comment: Would you humor me and try it with "Hello Again Extra Text!"?

Comment: @greeble31 =))))

Comment: What does that mean?